# How do I change caret direction to up when onclick

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I am trying to change the caret direction when I click on the link, here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Swathi56/5ak9uhzp/

HTML

```
<nav>
  <dl>
    <dt class="qp-ui goog-zippy-header goog-zippy-expanded" data-qp-ui="{ 'SideNavZippy': false }" tabindex="0" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" data-qp-ui-data-id="qp:6">Desktop</dt>
    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <dt class="nested-group qp-ui goog-zippy-header goog-zippy-expanded" data-qp-ui="{ 'SideNavZippy': false }" tabindex="0" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" data-qp-ui-data-id="qp:7">Hysys<b class="caret"></b></dt>
      <dd>
        <a href="hysys.html">Hysys</a>
      </dd>
    </div>
   </dl>
```